# intellij find in path always shows no occurrences

Tags: java, search, intellij-idea

Whenever i use Intellij find in path for the last few days, i get no results whatsoever.. I don't know what i've changed to create this scenario or what has broken.

even if i search within a scope and only include one folder with one file the search tool still cannot find anything.

For example i search for 'status' in Whole Project. It should return 1000's of results.
If i limit to *.java files and search in 'Directory' with a dir that only contains one java file with occurrences of 'status', intellij still cannot find it.

If i do a local search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>) i can find whatever i want in the currently open file..

Has anybody come across this issue before?

Thanks

Comment: Usually something like this happens if a file filter is applied, or the recursive search is disabled or something like this. Could you add a screenshot of the search window so we can see the options you are using?

Comment: Is the "search everywhere" broken too? (the looking glass in the upper right corner)

Comment: actually the search everywhere works. Still no luck with the find in path though..

Answer (score 51):

Seems I needed to go to file->Invalidate Caches and restart.. Maybe that will help someone with the same problem!

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot. You should accept your own answer to your question :)

Comment: Worked for me as well

Comment: I works for me, but after a while (like 20 seconds) Idea again doesn't return results. It looks like if it filters bunch of files from indexing. Is there a way to find indexing rules?

Comment: @cianBuckley, Placebo?

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same problem and all the solution provide above none work for me.

But i manage to resolve it like this.

1. Hold `Ctrl + Shift + f` to launch Find in path window.
2. ***Uncheck File mask*** button located at `Top-Right of Find in Path`

Only that and problem solved

[image: Find in path with File Mask checked]

[image]

Comment: that solved my problem, I forgot that I was using the file mask.

Answer (score 3):

As *cianBuckley* answered it sometimes has to do with corrupt caches; `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` will solve this.

For me it didn't. My search results were empty because of the `Recursively` option was disabled:

[image: Recursively option]

Answer (score 1):

Invalidating caches / restarting does NOT work for me.

Removing the `.idea` folder works for me.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006877240-Find-in-Path-is-not-working

Here is mine:

```
Build #IU-191.6707.61, built on April 16, 2019

You have a perpetual fallback license for this version
Subscription is active until April 26, 2022
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b44 x86
JVM: OpenJDK Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Invalidating cache didn't work for me. But this did:

Hit `File -> Repair IDE` and do these steps

1. Refresh Indexes
2. Rescan indexes
3. Reopen Project
4. Check search is working as it should
5. Hit 'Everything works now'